# Unity3D: Rotating the head and an animation gets clashed

Tags: unity, animation, rotation, mecanim

A rigged generic models head keeps rotating to follow the camera. When there is an animation like shaking the head, the head animates weirdly as compared to without rotation. Is there anyway to fix it?

The neck gets protruded forward.

```
the heirarchy is like spine
                           neck
                               neck_02
                                     head #here is my rotation script
```

For some reason, if I attach the script to neck, the neck doesn't rotate.

The neck gets protruded forward when the head shaking animation occurs

Comment: can you add an Image or gif to show the problem?

Comment: @SeyedMortezaKamali I'm not sure if I am allowed to as its a private property...I can explain it more if you want

Comment: Then reproduce the problem with another model that is not confidential, and show us that.